# Observing click events in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, html, click, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I'm having some issues trying to fire onclick events in CKEditor. I would like to be able to add a superscript element to CKEditor's editor content, click on it, and then execute some code, but this is not happening. Here is the code I've been using:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on('contentDom', function () {
    var elements = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.getElementsByTag('sup');
    for (var i = 0, c = elements.count(); i < c; i++) {
        var element = elements[i];
        CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.editable().attachListener(element, 'click', function () {
            alert("I've been clicked!");
        });
    }
});
```

Clicking on the elements I'd like this to be added to doesn't do anything; I'm expecting an alert window to pop up. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like a nice puzzle, but also like an xy problem. What is the reason for doing something like this? I'd most likely just use jquery and ignore the `CKEDITOR` event model for something like this, but I hesitate to try before understanding what it is I'm trying to achieve :)

Comment: Why mix jQuery if the CKEditor API should be enough to do the task? One of the most common problems that I see is that people try to use jQuery for everything when there's a simple approach available using the correct API.